# Need help searching memory locations backwards (Assembly Language)

Tags: assembly, 6502

Problem: Write an assembly language program that uses a
loop which searches backwards through memory
locations E001h - E0FFh for locations that contain
zeros and places the total into location 0500h.
Have the program start at 0200h in memory.
Assemble the program, load it into the emulator,
run it, and verify that it works correctly.

---

```
    org 0200h

    ldx #0d
    stx 0500h
Loop:
    lda 0e001h,x

    cmp #0d
    bne NoZ

    inc 0500h

NoZ:
    dex

    bne Loop

    brk 

    end
```

---

I'm not too familiar with low level programming so I (believe) I managed to do this forward but I'm struggling on searching the memory locations backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is not too bad, but has a bug. X wraps to FF so you check E100.

```
    org 0200h
    ldx #0d      ;I'm assuming this is 0 in an unusual decimal notation
    stx 0500h
Loop:
    lda 0e001h,x ;x is 0,FF,FE...1. So E001,E100(bug),E0FF...E002
    cmp #0d
    bne NoZ
    inc 0500h
NoZ:
    dex          ;x will wrap from 0 to FF
    bne Loop     ;x goes down to 1 (x=0 will break the loop)
    brk 
    end
```

If this is homework, your instructor actually set you up for success. Loops in assembly are often more natural, smaller, and faster when counting in reverse.

```
    org 0200h
    ldx #0d
    stx 0500h    ;Initialize 0500 to 0
    dex          ;x starts at FF
Loop:
    lda 0e000h,x ;Base address E000 and x is FF,FE...1. So E0FF,E0FE...E001
    cmp #0d
    bne NoZ
    inc 0500h
NoZ:
    dex
    bne Loop     ;x goes down to 1 (x=0 will break the loop)
    brk 
    end
```

The next optimization would be to use y for counting as per Eight-Bit Guru's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Off-the-cuff attempt, feels like there might be a faster way though...

```
    ldy #$00     ; set .Y = 0 (count of zeros)
    ldx #$00     ; set .X = 0 (address offset)
loop:
    dex          ; X = X - 1 (so $FF on first iteration)
    beq done     ; quit when .X hits 0
    lda $E000,x  ; get byte at $E000 + .X
    bne loop     ; go around if not 0
    iny          ; .Y = .Y + 1
    bne loop     ; go around (.Y can't be zero)
done:
    sty $0500    ; store count in .Y at $0500
    brk          ; GTFO
```

Edit: there was :)

```
    ldy #$00     ; set .Y = 0   (count of zeros)
    ldx #$FF     ; set .X = 255 (address offset)
loop:
    lda $E000,x  ; get byte at $E000 + .X
    bne sub1     ; skip counter increment if not zero
    iny          ; .Y = .Y + 1
sub1:
    dex          ; .X = .X - 1
    bne loop     ; quit when .X hits zero
    sty $0500    ; store count in .Y at $0500
    brk          ; GTFO
```